# CSS style different for one or two children

Tags: css

On a website I'm developing, I have a `div` that can contains one or more children. In the case where there is one child, I would like it to be as wide as it needs to be. In the case where there are two or more children, I would like the maximum width to be 50% so that two can be displayed side by side. So it should look like:

[image]

For the CSS, I know I can accomplish the second effect with

```
.inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

I'm not sure how to manipulate the selectors to apply different styling if there's one vs. 2+ inner `div`s.

Comment: you missed to explain what's the expected result when **three** items are present and their respective widths: You can always use *nth-child* CSS selector and handle those special cases....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**CSS flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) might be really easy and handy in that circumstance:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container > * {
  flex: 1;
  background: #6ef790;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

To limit the **width to 50%** use

```
flex: 1 0 50%;
```

`50%`, or account for margins using *`calc(50% - <margin*2>px)`*

Example:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container > * {
  flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 20px); /* 20px are 10px * 2 margin for one element */
  margin: 10px;
  background: #6ef790;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solves half the problem. If there are two or more, I want the max width locked to 50% because otherwise they will get too small.

Comment: @Aliden that's not stated in your initial Question about what's the expected behavior when three elements are inside a single parent container. Can you explain the desired result? Three children... should all three be 100% Only the first one? the last one? Or have all three at 50% (with the third one occupying the next row by just being 50% in width?)

Comment: @Aliden because in such case who said you cannot create another container and use `@media` queries to handle mobile or desktop?! Your request just become a bit unclear. Given the provided question and the two use cases.

Comment: Your second option is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` on the outer div, with the following settings on the children:

Here's the example with one child element:

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a>div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    flex: 1 1 40%;
    background: #eee;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

And here with two children and the same CSS :

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a>div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    flex: 1 1 40%;
    background: #eee;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

And here with 4 children, still the same CSS :

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a>div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    flex: 1 1 40%;
    background: #eee;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if there are 3 or more elements? Do they continue on the same line or wrap to the next? You may have missed it in the question, but I don't want there to ever be more than two children in the same row.

Comment: Yes, that also works  - iI  just added a 3rd example (and changed the last CSS rule which created the margin between the child elements).

Comment: With more than 2 elements, it fails to wrap to a second line. There should be at most two children on one line.

Comment: Okay, here's another version (all examples edited, same CSS everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

In a case you like [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (as me)

```
div{
width: 100vw;            /* or 100%, ... */
text-align: center;
}
p{                          /* your .inner */
box-sizing: border-box;
max-width: 49%;             /* this is safe - always enough of space */
display: inline-block;      /* this to place them together */
margin: 10px auto;          /* you may change 10px but keep auto!! */
}
```

```
<div><p></p></div>                 <!-- p is wide as needs, at least 49%, central -->
<div><p></p><p></p></div>          <!-- twice goes as twins  --->
<div><p></p><p></p><p></p></div>   <!-- twins and 3rd bottom central -->
```

You knew how to do it - just fill with content for tests.
Watch out for `display: flex` it leaks...

Comment: Never *just* mix % and px.